# Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined - Excel Function definition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to define the following function but am getting `Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined`. The debugged is highlighting the first line. Any ideas as to what could be incorrect here?

```
Function MAXELSEMIN(A As Integer, B As Double, C As Double) As Double
If A = 1 Then
    test = Max(B, C)
ElseIf A = -1 Then
    test = Min(B, C)
Else
    test = 0
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`WorksheetFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) object to call the functions in question:

```
test = WorksheetFunction.Max(B, C)

test = WorksheetFunction.Min(B, C)
```

and then at the end add the line:

```
MAXELSEMIN = test
```